# How to uppercase the text property of UILabel from Swift subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I created a Swift subclass for `UILabel` in my app to manage its styling across all views so it will be easier to modify the styles later on. I know that to convert a string to uppercase, I can just use either `uppercased()` to achieve that.

However, the problem lies when I use `uppercased()` or `capitalized` within the subclass for the `UILabel` text property, it doesn't work on runtime. What's weird is that it's being rendered correctly on the storyboard (with `@IBDesignable`), but in runtime, it shows the uncapitalized string.

For example, I have a code similar to this in the `UILabel` subclass:

```
textColor = ...
font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 12.0)
text = text!.uppercased()
```

And then in the view controller, I have a code similar to this:

```
label_noWeightMessage.text = "No weight logs this week..."
```

The color and the font is being applied correctly, except for the case change. Am I missing something here?

In the storyboard, the text is being shown as "NO WEIGHT LOGS THIS WEEK..."
but in the simulator at runtime, it reverts back to the original case.

I know that I can just type the text in caps. But that's not what I want. I want to be able to reuse the styling across all screens without having to retype all the `UILabel` texts and just change it in one place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text is not set to uppercase when it changes. Convert to uppercase in the `didSet` section of the `text` property in your overridden `UILabel`.

If you want to change the text for labels that have their texts set up through Interface Builder, override `awakeFromNib` as well:

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            super.text = text?.uppercased()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        super.text = text?.uppercased()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to call `super.text = text?.uppercased()` in your didSet

Comment: @rbaldwin Ahh, of course. I created an infinite loop. Thanks!